# Getting Windows Version

Tags: operating-system, version

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit) Build 17763. I am writing a program where i need to check for windows version. I know there are different ways of doing this, but the problem is, each method brings out different result, and i am kindof confused why it should be so.

VB.Net

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion.Version)
```

Outputs: 6.2.9200 (Major: 6, Minor: 2, Build: 9200)

Powershell

```
[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version
```

Outputs: Outputs: 10.0.17763 (Major: 10, Minor: 0, Build: 17763)

Java

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.version"));
```

Outputs: 6.3 (which i guess Major is 6 while minor is 3)

Now, as you can see, all results are not the same. I need to know why, and which result to work with. Thanks